# Form only Submitting on 2nd Attempt

Tags: php, forms, web

I have created a form for a quiz, where you have to enter the answers and a PHP script will total them and send them to en E-Mail address and save them to a file. However, the user is only redirected on the 2nd attempt (submission) of the form. The results are totalled and sent on the first submission, but it does not redirect. On the 2nd submission, the results are not totalled, but an e-mail is sent and the user is redirected to the completion page.

Here is my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Quiz</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) $username = $_SESSION['username'];
else header("Location: http://quiz.dibdibguy.com/client/index");

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/scripts/sql.php");
$qid = $_SESSION['quiz'];
$con = connect();
$data = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `qs` WHERE `id`='$qid' LIMIT 1");
$qinfo = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
<body><div id="white">&nbsp; </div>
<div id="content" class="text">
<div class="header">Quizzes</div>
<div class="subheader">Quiz: <?php echo($qinfo['name']); ?></div>


<table width="85%" class="menu text" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div align="center"><?php if ($qinfo['desc'] == NULL) echo($qinfo['name'] . ", has no description available."); else echo($qinfo['desc']); ?></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<?php
$table = $qinfo['table'];
$questionsTable = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `$table`");
?>
<table width="85%" class="menu text" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div align="left"><b>Please Remember:</b> For questions that require you to type an answer, you must spell it correctly, as the system cannot detect spelling errors.<br>
    <b>Playing as: <i><?php echo($_SESSION['username']); ?></i></b></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table width="85%" class="menu text" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <form method="post" name="quiz" action="">
    <?php
    $amt = mysqli_num_rows($questionsTable);
    $count = 1;
    echo($questions['que']);
    while($ques = mysqli_fetch_array($questionsTable)){
        echo("Question: " . $ques['que'] . "<br>");
        echo("Answer: <input type=\"text\" name=\"$count\"><br><br>");
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Answers" id="btn">
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $answers = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ans` FROM `$table`");
    $u_answers = $_POST;
    $correct = 0;
    while($answer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($answers)){
        echo("Hi");
        foreach($u_answers as $u_ans){
            if ($answer['ans'] == strtolower($u_ans)) $correct = $correct + 1;
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
    }
    header("Location: http://quiz.dibdibguy.com/client/index");
    #WRITE DATA TO FILE
    $file = fopen("../results/" . strtoupper($_SESSION['username']) . "_" . date("d-m-Y_h:i_sa") . "_" .  strtoupper($_SESSION['quiz'] . ".txt"), 'w');
    fwrite($file, ($correct) . "/" . ($amt));
    fclose($file);

    mail("aaron@dibdibguy.com", $_SESSION['username'] . "quiz results", $correct . "/" . $amt);
    $_SESSION['quiz'] = $qinfo['name'];
}
close($con);
?>

<br>
<?php include "../footer.php"; ?>

<br>
<br>&nbsp;
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

On the 1st attempt, if I get 1 question correct, I receive an e-mail stating; '1/39', which is what should happen, but on the 2nd attempt, I get an e-mail stating '0/', even if I get some correct.

Thanks in advance for any assistance. If you need anything else, please, E-Mail me (aaron@dibdibguy.com), or comment on this question!

Web Host: unlimitedwebhosting

PHP Version: 5.5

Comment: Never mind.Do not worry about it..

Comment: It's not a login form at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems.

First - HTML headers have to be sent before *any* content is sent. If you look in your error logs there are likely warnings about this. You print quite a lot of html to the page before your location header is used for the redirect. Since it's too late for headers it's ignored (you don't get redirected).  To fix this either move the redirect logic further up the page before any output (and plain HTML counts as output) or use [output_buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to keep the output from being sent to the browser until you've sent all your headers.

Second - The '0/' email seems to be an error in your logic. If you look at this block:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    ... Other Stuff

    mail("aaron@dibdibguy.com", $_SESSION['username'] . "quiz results", $correct . "/" . $amt);

    ... More Stuff
}
```

The logic you've written says that the email will be sent any time the submit button is pressed. You never did a 'sanity check' to see if you actually have any valid information in the form first.

Comment: Also your attempt to redirect the user if they haven't logged in (don't have a session) is going to fail for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good answer :)
I've fixed it myself, so I'll include your answer with the method I have used.